# How to Export Data from Mathematica into Excel specific cell

Tags: export, excel

for import,we can do like this
Import["XXX.xlsx", {"Data",1,2,3}],Mathematica will get the cell {2,3} of the "sheet1" in "XXX.xlsx".
But if we want to export data from Mathematica to one Excel specific cell,How to realize?

Comment: Strongly related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15835/193

Comment: Would padding the rest of the table with empty strings be sufficient?  (Note that you cannot *append* to an existing XLS file, keeping all the entries.  The only option is to completely overwrite it.  If you need to append, you'd need to read in the data first, add the modification, then write out the whole table again.)

Comment: Perhaps you could look at [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17379) where the access to individual excel cells is used for another purpose