# Get the complement date range

Tags: date-and-time, intersection

Suppose that I have a date range list

```
drlist = {{"2015-01-01", "2015-01-05"}, 
          {"2015-01-07", "2015-01-07"}, 
          {"2015-01-12", "2015-01-23"}}
```

and a range of date

```
sdate = "2015-01-04";
edate = "2015-01-14";
r = {sdate, edate};
```

to make things easy to understand, `{"2015-01-04", "2015-01-14"}` in reality represent something like `{"2015-01-04-00-00","2015-01-14-12-00"}`, i.e., the date start from 0:00 but end at some time of the day, say "12:00" is enough for me.

Then my question is how can I get the range of date that in `r` but not in `drlist`, e.g., it should be output something like:

```
cdrlist = {{"2015-01-05", "2015-01-06"}, {"2015-01-07", "2015-01-11"}}
```

and if we set `endate = "2015-01-25"`, then the output should be

```
cdrlist = {{"2015-01-05", "2015-01-06"}, 
           {"2015-01-07", "2015-01-11"}, 
           {"2015-01-23", "2015-01-25"}}
```

It should be noted that in this case the day "25" should be <del>contained</del> included.

**UPDATE**

To clarify the confusing results I were demonstrated, let us just consider the day, the day range we have is union of closed intervals:
$$ 
drlist=[1.0,5.5]\sqcup[7.0,7.5]\sqcup[12.0,23.5]
$$
and the day range we set is just a closed interval:
$$ 
r=[4.0,25.5]
$$
thus the set $r\setminus drlist$ equals to
$$ 
r\setminus drlist=(5.5,7)\sqcup(7.5,12)\sqcup(23.5,25.5],
$$
and translated this back to day range shoulde be
$$
5-6,7-11,23-25.
$$
Let me explain why $(5.5,7)$ should be $5-6$? Note that in our notation, $5-6$ represent $[5.0,6.5]$ which is exactly the interval contains $(5.5,7)$, since the $0.5$ should be understand very close to $1.0$. Also $(23.5,25.5]=(24,26)=[23,25]$ in above sense.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "day 25 should be contained".

Comment: Somewhat related: [(11746)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11746/121)

Comment: I don't understand why dates `"2015-01-06"` and `"2015-01-07"` in the output are not considered contiguous, yielding a single range `cdrlist = {{"2015-01-05", "2015-01-11"}}`.  Would you clarify this please?

Comment: @Kuba Pardon me, what?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `"2015-01-06"` is `"2015-01-06" at 12:00. so there is 12h to "2015-01-07".

Comment: @Kuba Ah, I wasn't thinking on those terms.  I may need a different approach.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, now I know what was not ok for me. Let's switch to only days for simplicity. And let's `drlist = {{1,2}}` which schould be intepreted as `{1, 2.5}`. But if we want to take away `{0, 1} (*{0,1.5}*)` then the exact result should be `{1.5, 2.5}` which in "base form" is `{1,2}` so even though the intersection is not empty, the `drlist` is the same.

Comment: @Kuba So you feel the question is underspecified and cannot be answered as written, or you simply note a weakness in the chosen format?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, now I'm sure this is a fatal problem :) The correct answer to OP's example should be `{{5.5, 7}, {7.5, 12}}` but with current notation it is at least tought to remain consistent.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for clear me to Wizard, That is what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim it is impossible to remain consistent with your convention of adding hours to second elements. Either we keep track of hours everythwere or we are in trouble.

So now I'm going to ignore that :)

```
drlist = {{"2015-01-01", "2015-01-05"}, 
          {"2015-01-07", "2015-01-08"}, 
          {"2015-01-12", "2015-01-23"}};
r = {"2015-01-04", "2015-01-14"};
```

I'm going to work on seconds:

```
restTime = Interval @@ Partition[Flatten[{0, Map[AbsoluteTime, drlist, {2}], 10^10}],
                                 2]

main = Interval[AbsoluteTime /@ r]
```

> ```
> Interval[{0, 3629059200}, {3629404800, 3629577600}, 
>          {3629664000, 3630009600}, {3630960000, 10000000000}]
>
> Interval[{3629318400, 3630182400}]
> ```

```
List @@ Map[DateList[#][[;; 3]] &, 
            IntervalIntersection[main, restTime],
            {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{2015, 1, 5}, {2015, 1, 7}}, {{2015, 1, 8}, {2015, 1, 12}}}
> ```

I'm living formatting to you. Also, if you want to add `DatePlus` for those second elements, feel free to do so :)

Comment: Very nice. +1   .

Comment: Reminds me of this: [(42660)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42660/121)

Comment: @Kuba, "it is impossible to remain consistent " - even using V10 `TimeObject`?

Comment: @alancalvitti If you keep all information sure, but OP wants to store dates with "day" precisison only. Also, maybe I'm wrong and it will not be a problem but I don't like it so let me ignore it :)

Comment: @Kuba, this approach using `AbsoluteTime` normal form to leverage  `Interval` arithmetic has appeal. Have you thought about generalizing to dates and times?  Temporal logic is critical in databases nowadays.

Comment: @alancalvitti it should work for full dates too. I'm just not sure if such approach will be fast enough and how precise `AbsoluteTime` is, in terms of leap seconds etc etc.

Comment: @Kuba, there are known issues with it, eg http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15063/is-there-a-way-to-get-absolutetime-to-correctly-report-absolute-time-differences. Leap timing is a real concern and affects everyone, not just W platform. This recently in the Journal: http://www.wsj.com/articles/planned-june-leap-second-stirs-a-timely-debate-1421430888

Answer (score 2):

This first part finds the complementary dates.

```
sdate = "2015-01-04";
edate = "2015-01-14";
r = {sdate, edate};

drlist = {
   {"2015-01-01", "2015-01-05"},
   {"2015-01-07", "2015-01-07"},
   {"2015-01-12", "2015-01-23"}};

If[$VersionNumber == 10,
 fromDate[datelist_List] :=
  QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[{1899, 12, 30}, datelist],
 fromDate[datelist_List] := DateDifference[{1899, 12, 30}, datelist]] (* Note 1 *)

undoDate[int_Integer] := StringJoin@Riffle[
   ToString /@ DatePlus[{1899, 12, 30}, int] , "-"]

r2 = r /. a_String :> fromDate[Take[DateList[{a, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}}], 3]];
drlist2 = drlist /. a_String :> fromDate[Take[DateList[{a, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}}], 3]];

r3 = Range[0, #2 - #1] + #1 & @@ r2;
drlist3 = Union@Flatten[Range[0, #2 - #1] + #1 & @@@ drlist2];

cdrlist1 = Complement[r3, drlist3];
undoDate /@ cdrlist1
```

> {"2015-1-6", "2015-1-8", "2015-1-9", "2015-1-10", "2015-1-11"}

Now finding the date ranges.  (It would be interesting to see better ways of doing this.)

```
cdrlist2 = Transpose[{cdrlist1,
    Append[Differences@cdrlist1 /. x_ /; x > 1 -> 0, 0]}];

If[cdrlist2[[1, 2]] == 1, output = {},
  output = List@Take[cdrlist2, 1];
  cdrlist2 = Rest@cdrlist2];

While[Length[cdrlist2] > 0,
 a = TakeWhile[cdrlist2, Last[#] == 1 &];
 b = Drop[cdrlist2, Length[a]];
 If[b == {}, AppendTo[output, a],
  AppendTo[a, First[b]];
  AppendTo[output, a];
  cdrlist2 = Rest[b]]]

cdrlist3 = Replace[output, x_List /; Length[x] > 1 :> x[[{1, -1}]], {1}];

cdrlist = cdrlist3 /. {a_Integer, _Integer} :> undoDate[a]
```

> {{"2015-1-6"}, {"2015-1-8", "2015-1-11"}}

Note 1. `fromDate[]` actually converts a date to an [Excel serial date](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17368/converting-excel-serial-dates-with-netlink), but valid only from 1st March 1990 due to Excel's compatibility carry-over of the Lotus 1-2-3 [leap-year](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html) bug. (1990 is not a leap-year.)

Answer (score 2):

I do not follow your logic for why `{{"2015-01-05", "2015-01-06"}, {"2015-01-07", "2015-01-11"}}` is split into two ranges since `"2015-01-06"` and `"2015-01-07"` are adjacent, however overlooking that here is a fairly clean approach.

Helper functions:

```
toList[x : {_String, _String}, os_: {12, "Hour"}] := 
  MapAt[DatePlus[#, os] &, DateRange @@ DateList /@ x, -1]

toString = DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}] &;
```

And with data:

```
drlist = {{"2015-01-01", "2015-01-05"},
          {"2015-01-07", "2015-01-07"},
          {"2015-01-12", "2015-01-23"}};

r = {"2015-01-04", "2015-01-25"};
```

Process:

```
Complement[toList[r], Join @@ toList /@ drlist];

#[[{1, -1}]] & /@ Split[%, #[[3]] + 1 == #2[[3]] &];

Map[toString, %, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{"2015-01-05", "2015-01-11"}, {"2015-01-23", "2015-01-25"}}
> ```

---

You may also find inspiration from answers to my own question back on Stack Overflow:

- [Overlapping strips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784046/618728)

Comment: The OP says he wants "the range of date that in `r` but not in `drlist`", but you have returned "2015-01-05" which *is* in `drlist`.

Comment: @Chris the OP includes `"2015-01-05"` in his own output example!  The format is not clear.

Comment: I think he just made that up. He also has "2015-01-06" and "2015-01-07" which should be merged into the same range.